# PHP: Формат даты

Tags: дата, php, html

Пришла ко мне дата формата:

> 27.12.2010

Как мне вставить ее в верстку, чтобы получилось так:

```
<div class="date">
    <span class="day">27</span>
    <span class="month">дек</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function format_date($date)
{     
  $mon=array(1=>'янв','фев','мар','апр','май','июн', 'июл','авг','сен','окт','ноя','дек');
  if(preg_match("/^(\d{2})\.(\d{2})/",$date,$m))
  return "<div class='date'><span class='day'>".$m[1]."</span><span class='month'>".$mon[$m[2]]."</span></div>";
  return "";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать оператор `echo`

```
<span class="day">echo $day</span>
<span class="month">echo $month</span>
```

я так понимаю вам нужно сначала получить отдельные параметры даты. Использовать можно [функции даты и времени](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.datetime.php).
или регулярки ,в зависимости от того какая у вас задача.

```
$time=strtotime('27.12.2010');
echo 'day'.date('d',$time);
```